# ElasticSearch circuit_breaking_exception (Data too large) with significant_terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, significant-terms

The query:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "sigTerms": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "translatedTitle"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "assocs": {
          "significant_terms": {
            "field": "translatedTitle"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "lt": "now+1d/d",
        "gte": "now/d"
      }
    }
  },
  "track_scores": false
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "bytes_limit": 6844055552,
  "bytes_wanted": 6844240272,
  "reason": "[request] Data too large, data for [<reused_arrays>] would be larger than limit of [6844055552/6.3gb]",
  "type": "circuit_breaking_exception"
}
```

Index size is 5G. How much memory does the cluster need to execute this query?

Comment: @AndreiStefan ES version is 2.2.0

Answer (score 11):

You can try to increase the [request circuit breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html#circuit-breaker) limit to 41% (default is 40%) in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file and restart your cluster:

```
indices.breaker.request.limit: 41%
```

Or if you prefer to not restart your cluster you can change the setting dynamically using:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
  "persistent" : {
    "indices.breaker.request.limit" : "41%" 
  }
}'
```

Judging by the numbers showing up (i.e. `"bytes_limit": 6844055552, "bytes_wanted": 6844240272`), you're just missing ~190 KB of heap, so increasing by 1% to 41% you should get 17 MB of additional heap (your total heap = ~17GB) for your request breaker which should be sufficient.

Just make sure to not increase this value too high, as you run the risk of going OOM since the request circuit breaker also shares the heap with the fielddata circuit breaker and other components.

Comment: Hey @esp, have you been able to try this out?

Comment: That's not how required memory estimation works - `bytes_wanted` is not an accurate number but rather an approximation. Lifting the limit by a small percentage will likely result in the same error, just with a slightly higher `bytes_limit`/`bytes_wanted` values.

Comment: That was just to illustrate, of course if he takes this approach he'll need to try and see what works for him.

Comment: Use this if you are using ElasticSearch 6.0 and above, and requires authentication ```curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -u elastic:PASSWORD localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "persistent" : { "indices.breaker.request.limit" : "45%" }}'```

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I'm curious to find out. Since you get that exception, I can assume the cardinality of that field is not small. You are basically trying to see, I guess, the relationships between all the terms in that field, based on significance.

The first `significant_terms` aggregation will consider **all** the terms from that field and establish how "significant" they are (calculating frequencies of that term in the whole index and then comparing those with the frequencies from the `range` query set of documents).

After it's doing that (for all the terms), you want a second `significant_aggregation` that should do the first step, but now considering each term and doing for it another `significant_aggregation`. That's gonna be painful. Basically, you are computing `number_of_term * number_of_terms` significant_terms calculations.

The big question is ***what are you trying to do***?

If you want to see a relationship between all the terms in that field, that's gonna be expensive for the reasons explained above. My suggestion is to run a first `significant_terms` aggregation, take the first 10 terms or so and then run a second query with another `significant_terms` aggregation but limiting the terms by probably doing a parent `terms` aggregation and [include only those 10 from the first query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2).

You can, also, take a look at [sampler aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) and use that as a parent for your **only one** significant terms aggregation.

Also, I don't think increasing the circuit breaker limit is the real solution. Those limits were chosen with a reason. You can increase that and maybe it will work, but it has to make you ask yourself if that's the *right query* for your use case (as it doesn't sound like it is). That limit value that it's in the exception might not be the final one... `reused_arrays` refers to an array class in Elasticsearch that is resizeable, so if more elements are needed, the array size is increased and you may hit the circuit breaker again, for another value.

Answer (score 5):

Circuit breakers are designed to deal with situations when request processing needs more memory than available. You can set limit by using following query

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "indices.breaker.request.limit" : "45%" 
  }
}
```

You can get more information on

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-fielddata.html